# Why do I get a syntax error when activating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to make a virtual environment for a Flask application and I get this error when I try to activate it:

```
C:\Users\jessa\Desktop\travaux-pratiques\tp4-web-bbelzile\depart>python ./env/Scripts/activate  
  File "./env/Scripts/activate", line 4
    deactivate (){
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's not the first time that I try to make an env but it is the first time that I get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
C:\...\depart>python ./env/Scripts/activate
```

You are trying to run the activation script **as a Python script/file**. That's not a Python script and should not be run with a Python interpreter.

As indicated in the [virtual environment docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments):

> Once a virtual environment has been created, it can be “activated” using a script in the virtual environment’s binary directory. The invocation of the script is platform-specific (*`<venv>`* must be replaced by the path of the directory containing the virtual environment):
>
> ```
> Windows | cmd.exe    | C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat
>         | PowerShell | PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1
> ```

(*I'm assuming you are activating it on Windows based on the path*)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem while activating your Flask virtual environment.

You can activate by using

```
cd /env/script
activate.bat
```

Or you can activate using your Powershell

```
source env/bin/activate
```